# How to render Json Request and Html template both from one flask Api?

Tags: python, flask

```
@adm.route('/list_users', methods=['GET'])
@login_required`enter code here`
@admin_permission.require(http_exception=403)
def list_users():
    try:
        if (request.content_type.startswith('application/json')):
        def processjsonlist():
        @csrf.exempt
          try:
             page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
             recs = current_app.config.get('RECORDS_PER_PAGE')
             list_user = Person.query.order_by(
                Person.id).paginate(page, recs, False)
             rv = []
             for person in list_user.items:
                tmp = {}
                tmp['id']=person.id
                tmp['username'] = person.username
                tmp['first_name'] = person.first_name
                tmp['middle_name'] = person.middle_name
                tmp['last_name'] = person.last_name
                tmp['employee_code'] = person.employee_code
                tmp['active'] = person.active
                tmp['email'] = person.email
                tmp['mobile'] = person.mobile
                tmp['roles'] = [role.description for role in person.roles]
                rv.append(tmp)
             return jsonify({"data": rv})

          except Exception as error:
            return jsonify(error=repr(error))
        else:
            page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
            recs = current_app.config.get('RECORDS_PER_PAGE')
            pagination = Person.query.order_by(
                Person.id).paginate(page, recs, False)
        search_form = SearchForm()
        return render_template('adm/user_list.html', pagination=pagination, 
           search_form=search_form)
    except Exception as e:
        flash_exception(e, 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('adm.getIndex'))
```

Comment: You can not render json and html, both are structural langage for data. You have to make a choice. Although you might factorize your code to reuse it in the json api endpoint and html endpoint.

Comment: This means I can't render JSON Request and HTML templates both from a single endpoint (URL).

Comment: @AryanGupta I think Emile is saying that you can't render both JSON and HTML for a single request. On the other hand, you CAN render JSON and HTML from the same endpoint for different requests.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `def processjsonlist():`? While you can define a function inside another function, this feature of Python is commonly used in very narrow circumstances and isn't appropriate here. Even if it were, you don't ever call this function, so it never does anything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render both HTML and JSON in the same response for a single request. However, you can allow the `Accept` header to determine whether an endpoint renders HTML or JSON. The entire response must be one or the other, but can't be mixed. I haven't used flask, so I don't know the exact details of how to do this with your project. Hopefully this will give you some terms to help with your google search.